# Python turtle stops responding after starting a loop

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm making a decision based game using loops inputs and stuff for a end of the year project. That includes all that we have learn this year and I have stumbled upon an issue that I have no clue how to fix. When I attempt to start a loop after running my turtle code, I get a not responding screen.

I tried putting a main loop after my turtle code, but that would not allow me to continue with my game. So I tried putting it at the end of the code and it still did not work. The turtles don't stop or anything they still move, but  when you continue with the game by entering your choice, the turtles confine moving.

I am also using the latest version of turtle and python. I don't know how to fix this so if someone could help me that would be nice.

Note: The code is an example and not the actual game and that the error occurs during the input.

```
import turtle
windw = turtle.Screen()
char = turtle.Turtle()

char.goto(0,10)
XD = True
while(XD):
    q = input("enter p")
```

Comment: Try providing a [mcve]

Comment: @PasserBy i added a example instead thanks for the criticism

Comment: Can you provide the error message?

Comment: It seems you have not indented `q = input("enter p")` inside the block of the `while` loop.

Comment: Are you running this code under some environment like IDLE or PyCharm?

Answer (score 0):

The input command is what is blocking it instead use something like:

```
ts = t.getscreen()
def callback():

    q = input("enter p")
    if q:
        dosomething()
#listens for the key q to be pressed
ts.onkey(callback,"q")
ts.listen()
t.mainloop()
```